# jquery get redirected url

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, mobile, jquery-mobile

Edit - 
Wasn't getting a response so let me ask this.  Can I do this?

```
<a href="http://m.facebook.com/...." target="_webapp">facebook button</a>
```

Let the page load on top of the current page and listen for the window.location.hostname before the page actually redirects with jquery?

---

Facebook site url = http://www.mysite.com

In a mobile app, you can use fb(YOUR_APP_ID)://authorize/ to request for auth_token.

Using jquery, how can I catch the redirected url before the page goes to it?

i.e.

```
CALLBACK_URL = fb(YOUR_APP_ID)://authorize/
url = "https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=CALLBACK_URL"
WebView.navigate(url)
WebView.execture_js('$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {
        if (xhr.getResponseHeader("Location").hostname == "fb(YOUR_APP_ID)://authorize/"){
            alert(xhr.getResponseHeader("Location"));
            // and redirect back to action in my app...
        }
    });
});')
```

Comment: 1. what does it have to do with jQuery Mobile Framework? 2. If I understand the question correctly - you can't. You can `bind` to the `click` on `a` and read its `href`

Comment: Using jquery mobile with rhomobile.  Hoping that there is something similar to how native apps work with jqm where it reads the redirected url before actually going to the page. In https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/Facebook.m around line 166 it sets the scheme or fbauth://authorize and in line 279 it looks for if the url starts with this and parses the token or error.

Comment: I refused to join facebook, so I have no idea how to use it, not to mention coding for it. I won't be able to help you with that facebook jibberish unless you preciselu define what you mean by `redirect` in terms of existing standards (like is it HTTP redirect? what redirects?), and how/when it happends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery Mobile, take a look at the pagebeforeshow event.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/api/events.html

```
$('div').live('beforepageshow', function(event, ui) {
    var page = $(this).attr("id");
    if (page == 'mypage') {
        // your logic here
    }
});
```

You might also try adding registering an ajaxComplete handler within a handler for the mobileinit event.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/api/globalconfig.html

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
  $("body").ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {
       if (xhr.getResponseHeader("Location").hostname == "fb(YOUR_APP_ID)://authorize/"){
            alert(xhr.getResponseHeader("Location"));
            // and redirect back to action in my app...
        }
  });
});
```